# How do I join multiple lists of uniform variables but different values into a single matrix?

Tags: python, list, matrix

I made N experiments and for each experiment I have a list of results with dates, i.e. I have N lists of the type `[[float1, date1], [float2, date2], ...]`

I want to make a matrix`(NxM)` of the results of all the experiments for the common dates.
What is the most efficient way to do it?

For example,

Given three experiments (N = 3) with values:

```
[[float1a, date1],
[float2a, date2],
[float3a, date3]]

[[float1b, date1],
[float2b, date2],
[float3b, date3]]

[[float1c, date1],
[float2c, date2],
[float3c, date3],
[float3, date4]]
```

I would like to produce something like:

```
date1 - float1a float1b float1c
date2 - float2a float2b float2b
date3 - float3a float3b float3c
```

Comment: do you have one list contain lists? so whats the dim of your list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at using pandas for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

expr1 = [[1.2,date(2012,1,1)], [1.3,date(2012,1,2)], [1.4,date(2012,1,3)]]
expr2 = [[1.2,date(2012,1,1)], [1.3,date(2012,1,2)], [1.4,date(2012,1,3)], [1.5,date(2012,1,4)]]
expr3 = [[1.2,date(2012,1,1)], [1.3,date(2012,1,2)], [1.4,date(2012,1,3)]]

exper_df1 = pd.DataFrame(expr1).set_index(1).rename(columns={0: "Result_1"})
exper_df2 = pd.DataFrame(expr2).set_index(1).rename(columns={0: "Result_2"})
exper_df3 = pd.DataFrame(expr3).set_index(1).rename(columns={0: "Result_3"})

experiments = [exper_df2, exper_df3]

exper_df = exper_df1.join(experiments, how='inner')
```

This produces a single DataFrame labelled by the dates you seek:

```
            Result_1  Result_2  Result_3
1                                       
2012-01-01       1.2       1.2       1.2
2012-01-02       1.3       1.3       1.3
2012-01-03       1.4       1.4       1.4
```

Comment: Thank you! But it's not exactly that I want but very close. In your example, I want the result to be as follows:

              0  1            
2012-01-01  1.2  1.2
2012-01-02  1.3  1.3
2012-01-03  1.4  1.4

And if there is a date say 2012-01-04 for expr2 only than I want it to be dropped

Comment: @user2598356 - This is an inner join on the table. I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but by common dates you mean similar dates, you can create a dictionary where each key is a date, and the value is a list of experiments from that date.

```
{'date1': ['float1', 'float11', etc..], 'date2': [...], ... }
```

This will also allow easy access to results from a specific date.
it can be done the following way:

```
my_results_list =  [[float1, date1], [float2, date2], ...]
results_by_date = {}
for res_couple in results:
    date, result = res_couple
    if date not in results_by_date:
        results_by_date[date] = []
    results_by_date.append(result)
```

I'm certain there are better ways to do this performance wise if that is an issue, but you get the idea.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I ment that I want to find only common dates, i.e. the dates when I have results for all N experiments, there will be say M of such dates. And then make a matrix where I write the results of all N experiments for these M shared dates

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.asmatrix(data, dtype=None)` function ! this is an efficient way for create **MATRIX**

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[float1, date1], [float2, date2], ...])
matrix = np.asmatrix(x)
```